# Lazy Load for iframe is not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, lazy-loading

```
<style>
.desgin_iframe_dimn {
background: white;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
</style>
<iframe scrolling="no" id="lazy" class="desgin_iframe_dimn" data-src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
<p class="lazy">Click Here</p>
<script>
function LazyLoadIframe() {
$('.lazy').click(function() {
    $('#lazy').attr('src', function() {
        return $(this).data('src');
    });
});

$('#lazy').attr('data-src', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).removeAttr('src');
    return src;
});

}
LazyLoadIframe();
</script>
```

Demo is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitshah02/KK2X3/11)

Above code works well in other browsers also in IE9 & IE8 but not in IE7. how do i fix this ?

Comment: Iframes should get deprecated, why don't you use a div and $.get?

Comment: I have to use iframe as of now, so need to find solution for this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have this part in your code:

```
$('#lazy').attr('data-src', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).removeAttr('src');
    return src;
});
```

But since `#lazy` has no `src`, this might be the part that breaks it on IE7. Other browsers might work because that piece of code is executed before the iframe is declared in the html.

I think what you want is this:

**HTML**

Here I moved the data-src to the clickable `<p>`:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id="lazy" class="desgin_iframe_dimn"></iframe>
<p class="lazy" data-src="http://www.wikipedia.com/">Click Here</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.lazy').click(function() {
        $('#lazy').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    });
});
```

Where `$(function() { });` is executed on document load. Don't just call a function in the middle of the HTML, always consider to use `$(function() {});`

I also don't understand why you did `function() { return $(this).data('src') }` while you can just do `$(this).data('src')`, so I corrected that too.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/63rSL/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
Considering this `$(function() {});` how can i call this function at many places ?